# Add events to google calendar and yahoo calendar

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-api, yahoo

How  can I add an event to google calendar and yahoo calendar in asp.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download the api, review the api.
http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html

Note the section for creating events
From: http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#CreatingSingle

1. Authenticate to the service
2. Create the event

```
EventEntry entry = new EventEntry();

// Set the title and content of the entry.
entry.Title.Text = "Tennis with Beth";
entry.Content.Content = "Meet for a quick lesson.";

// Set a location for the event.
Where eventLocation = new Where();
eventLocation.ValueString = "South Tennis Courts";
entry.Locations.Add(eventLocation);

When eventTime = new When(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(2));
entry.Times.Add(eventTime);

Uri postUri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full");

// Send the request and receive the response:
AtomEntry insertedEntry = service.Insert(postUri, entry);
```

Comment: javascript: http://developer.mail.yahoo.com/om/docs/OpenapiPublic/Calendar.html    jQuery: http://keith-wood.name/icalendar.html  etc etc

Answer (score 2):

The following links may also help with yahoo calendar:

[Adding Events to Users Calendars – Part 2 – Web Calendars](http://richmarr.wordpress.com/2008/01/07/adding-events-to-users-calendars-part-2-web-calendars/)

[Adding Calendar Events to Yahoo](http://armcnallie.wordpress.com/2008/03/12/adding-calendar-events-to-yahoo/)

[Yahoo! Calendar "Add Event" Seed URL Parameters](http://chris.photobooks.com/tests/calendar/Notes.html)

Answer (score 0):

- Docs for google calendar: https://github.com/InteractionDesignFoundation/add-event-to-calendar-docs/blob/master/services/google.md (link example: `https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=Bithday&dates=20201231T193000Z/20201231T223000Z&details=With%20clowns%20and%20stuff&location=North%20Pole`)
- Docs for yahoo calendar: https://github.com/InteractionDesignFoundation/add-event-to-calendar-docs/blob/master/services/yahoo.md (link example: `https://calendar.yahoo.com/?v=60&st=st20201231T193000&DUR=0200&desc=With%20clowns%20and%20stuff&in_loc=North%20Pole`)